# Python3 mutable static class members

Tags: python-3.x

I have a need to use static classes functions a variables and all useable classes would inherit from a single parent that have all the common methods and variables.

Current behavior is that a class variable defined in the parent is not distict to each child and is shared among all childs (need it as discreed variable)

```py
class Parent(object):
    cls_var = list()

    @classmethod
    def cls_mthd(cls, a):
        cls.cls_var.append(a)

class ChildA(Parent):
    pass

ChildA.cls_mthd('A')

class ChildB(Parent):
    pass

ChildB.cls_mthd('B')

print(Parent.cls_var)
print(ChildA.cls_var)
print(ChildB.cls_var)
```

Output

```py
['A', 'B']
['A', 'B']
['A', 'B']
```

A workaround to get the desired behavior I managed to get is this, but I don't think this hack would be the best way to go

```py
class Parent(object):
    cls_var = dict()

    @classmethod
    def cls_mthd(cls, a):
        if cls.__name__ not in cls.cls_var:
            cls.cls_var[cls.__name__] = list()
        cls.cls_var[cls.__name__].append(a)

    @classmethod
    def tst(cls):
        return cls.cls_var[cls.__name__] if cls.__name__ in cls.cls_var else None

class ChildA(Parent):
    pass

ChildA.cls_mthd('A')

class ChildB(Parent):
    pass

ChildB.cls_mthd('B')

print(Parent.tst())
print(ChildA.tst())
print(ChildB.tst())
```

Output

```py
None
['A']
['B']
```

Comment: @excaza the answer there is about instance members and not class members as this question is. (or did i misunderstand something?)

Comment: Thank @excaza, but this wouldn't help, we need to be able to use static classes that won't be instantiated for this specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to have mutable static class members you could use a [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation):

```
class MutableClassVarMeta(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, namespace, **kwds):
        cls = super().__new__(meta, name, bases, namespace, **kwds)
        cls.cls_var = []
        return cls

class Parent(metaclass=MutableClassVarMeta):
    @classmethod
    def cls_mthd(cls, a):
        cls.cls_var.append(a)

class ChildA(Parent):
    pass

class ChildB(Parent):
    pass

ChildA.cls_mthd('A')
ChildB.cls_mthd('B')

print(Parent.cls_var)  # []
print(ChildA.cls_var)  # ['A']
print(ChildB.cls_var)  # ['B']
```

(or did you really want `None` as `Parent.cls_var`?)

i admit it is a bit more verbose than your workaround but (to me) it looks more pythonic...

---

**update**

as pointed out by [Blckknght](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1405065/blckknght) the metaclass could (and probably should) look simpler:

```
class MutableClassVarMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        cls.cls_var = []
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I have a few minor quibbles about the metaclass implementation. The first argument of `__new__` in a metaclass will the metaclass itself, not the class it's creating. So don't name it `cls`, but rather `meta` or similar. That lets you use `cls` later, for the instance of the metaclass (the actual class object). For this metaclass, you might skip `__new__` all together and give the metaclass an `__init__` method instead (which would take `cls` as its first argument).

Comment: @Blckknght thanks! that is a very good point. i tried to change the code according to your suggestion; if i messed up & that is not what you meant feel free to edit the answer.